# switching objects during a gesture (drag and drop)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating a calendar with drag and drop rearrangeable events.

The view hierarchy looks like this:
ViewController - ScrollView - CalendarWeekView - EventView

The scrollView has paging enabled, I show one week at a time. To enable continuous scrolling across weeks, I have three WeekCalendarView objects which I recycle as I scroll. The individual EventViews are subviews of the CalendarWeekView.

I want to be able to drag and drop a EventViews from one week to another.

I have drag and drop within the visible week working fine with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer setup on the EventViews. I added 'hot edges' to the WeekView to trigger scrolling, with this i have drag and drop from the current week to the week either side of it working.

But, if I scroll more than one week away from my initial week the view recycling happens and the WeekView which created and 'owns' the EventViews i'm dragging gets recycled (properties reset). The event object I'm dragging gets reset and reused, thus killing the drag behaviour (or at best changing the event being dragged mid drag!).

I imagine I need to decouple the dragging view from the WeekViews, create a new object for my Event whilst it's being dragged.

How do i pass the long-press gesture event from the EventView to this new object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i pass the long-press gesture event from the EventView to this new object?

Just as you suggest :D You can use `addTarget:action:` and `removeTarget:action:` to adjust what method on what object is called by the gesture recognizer. You can even have multiple targets simultaneously if you like.

In you're case, you probably want something like:

```
[g removeTarget:self action:NULL]; // Remove everything that this object added
[g addTarget:newObject action:newSEL];
```

---

EDIT: Since you're dragging a specific EventView, rather than creating a new one and dealing with shuffling GRs, try just moving the dragging EventView to another superview (possibly the scroll view, though I've even used the UIWindow for this kind of thing).

Comment: Very sorry, i prematurely accepted your answer. Your solution moved the target of the gesture to the new view, but when the original view is recycled the gesture recogniser itself (now targeting the new view) disappears. :(  Is it possible to move the gesture recogniser itself? i tried the obvious: dragView.gestureRecognizers = sender.gestureRecognizers; sender.gestureRecognizers = nil; But the nil kills the gesture.

Comment: The better way to switch which view owns a GR is with addGestureRecognizer: and removeGestureRecognizer:. But it is possible that removeGestureRecognizer: will reset the GR in the same way. See edits. You probably can just keep using the same view rather than moving the GR.

Comment: Moving the gestureRecogniser between the views worked! I loop through all the gestureRecognisers on the source view, find the LongPress one and add it with addGestureRecogniser to the destination view. Removing it from the source view appears to have no affect. Thanks for your help.